# Where was this picture of a seaside road taken?

Tags: uk, identify-this

[image: beach_cliff_road]

Can someone help identify which location this might in the UK? I've seen this in a movie. I know for sure that the movie is shot in the UK as the story is based in the UK.

Comment: A story being based in one country and the movie shot in the same country is not a given. Often they do take a lot of shots in studios or in an other country.

Comment: Can you please add as much information as you have, like which movie and which part of the UK you think it is? (We are willing to help but it is much easier when we know why and what you have already done.)

Comment: @Willeke: "It's remarkable how England looks in no way like southern California!"

Comment: Not unlike Slapton Sands, aside from the lack of sands.

Comment: Is the movie Staggered?

Comment: Despite the NYPD logos, [this  picture (BBC)](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/4F4F/production/_109430302_newport-road-filming.jpg) was taken in Cardiff (illustrating @Willeke's point)

Answer (score 28):

This looks very much like the Military Road (A3055) on the south coast of the Isle of Wight

Round about here (just outside Compton, on Google street view)

[image]

The fence posts to the right side of the road are there, but it looks as though the photo has forshortened the view somewhat (and the Google camera seems to be wide-angle).

Comment: Cool. This looks almost same!! thanks a lot

Comment: Looks good! Another one from StreetView: https://goo.gl/maps/vf2JTcqoV4FZo4eTA

Comment: You're close, but I think it's just a bit further west on this road, just past Compton Beach.  You can see the posts there (which appear to have had reflectors added since the original picture).  Get to where the "Hanover Point National Trust Car Park" is just behind you, and it's a closer match.

Comment: So it's straight outta Compton?

Comment: @Darrel Yep I estimate about [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.6560021,-1.4671453,3a,75y,275.57h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1skeIt56gnUKGUwGFVXbACfg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)